# updating Multiple rows in laravel elequent

Tags: php, laravel

I want to update all the rows having role_id of "1" in laravel. But this returning the following error :

Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '["2","3"]' for column 'menu_id' at row 1 (SQL: update `role_menus` set `menu_id` = ["2","3"], `role_id` = 1, `write` = ["1","0"], `read` = ["1","1"], `edit` = ["0","1"], `delete` = ["0","1"], `created_at` = 2022-03-05 04:22:59, `role_menus`.`updated_at` = 2022-03-05 04:22:59 where `role_id` = 1)
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/update_role/1

**My codes so far are :**

*Controller :*

```
    public function updateRole(Request $request, $id){
    
    $update_role=array(
        'menu_id'=> $request->menu_id,
        'role_id'=> $request->role_id,
        'write'=> $request->write,
        'read'=> $request->read,
        'edit'=> $request->edit,
        'delete'=> $request->delete,
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()
    );

    $role_updated = RoleMenu::where('role_id','=',$id)->update($update_role);

    if($role_updated){
       echo $message = "Role Updated Successfully"; 
    }else{
       echo $message = "Something Went Wrong !"; 
    }
    // return json_encode($message);
}
```

*Codes from my html :*

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/update_role/1" method="POST">
<div>
    <input type="text" name="menu_id[]" value="2">
    <input type="text" name="role_id[]" value="1">
    <input type="text" name="write[]">
    <input type="text" name="read[]">
    <input type="text" name="edit[]">
    <input type="text" name="delete[]">
</div>

<div>
    <input type="text" name="menu_id[]" value="3">
    <input type="text" name="role_id[]" value="1">
    <input type="text" name="write[]">
    <input type="text" name="read[]">
    <input type="text" name="edit[]">
    <input type="text" name="delete[]">
</div>

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You are storing the array in the int column (menu_id). Please correct the datatype of the menu_id. That will solve the issue.

Comment: @HarishPatel, which dataType should be used ?

Comment: If you want to store array in database, Use JSON dataType for it. I can see that you are storing array for all fields. why are you doing this this way?

Comment: @HarishPatel Actually I am trying to update multiple rows, but don't know why they are appearing like write = ["1","0"], read = ["1","1"] instead of array(['write' => 1, 'read'=>1],['write' => 0, 'read'=>0])

Answer (score -1):

Change your all form input fields as below

```
<input type="text" name="role[0]['menu_id']" value="2">Menu

..........
```

Change in your controller for prepareing array and storing in table as below

```
foreach($request->role as $role) {
    $update_role = array(
        'menu_id'=> $request->menu_id,
        'role_id'=> $request->role_id,
        'write'=> $request->write,
        'read'=> $request->read,
        'edit'=> $request->edit,
        'delete'=> $request->delete,
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()
    );
    $role_updated = RoleMenu::where('role_id','=',$id)->update($update_role);
}
```

Hope this will work

Answer (score -1):

It should look like this:

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="menu_id" value="2">
<input type="text" name="role_id" value="1">
<input type="text" name="write">
<input type="text" name="read">
<input type="text" name="edit">
<input type="text" name="delete">
```

And PHP

```
 $update_role=array(
    'menu_id'=> $request->menu_id,
    'role_id'=> $request->role_id,
    'write'=> $request->write,
    'read'=> $request->read,
    'edit'=> $request->edit,
    'delete'=> $request->delete,
    'created_at' => Carbon::now()
);

$role_updated = RoleMenu::where('role_id','=',$id)->update($update_role);
```